# Room - Query calling collect Flow multitple times

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I am with some problem here.

I am using Room with Flow, and a simple query is calling my collect in a loop. I don't know what is happening.

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE login = :login")
 fun getUser(login:String):User?

override suspend fun getUser(login: String): Flow<Resource<User>> = flow {
    emit(Resource.loading())
    dao.getUser(login).collect {
        println("Hey, look at me")
    }
}.flowOn(Dispatchers.Default)
```

Anyone knows how to avoid it?

P.S.: Using a list as a query`s return, everything works fine.

Comment: What does 'calling my collect in a loop' mean? Note that you ever seem to actually `emit` your `User` in your code.

Comment: @ianhanniballake ops, I put the wrong code. Know is correctly

Comment: its printing the message in a loop